# Can you limit what characters can be typed into a MATLAB GUI editbox?

Tags: user-interface, matlab, matlab-guide, editbox

I want to make an editbox in a MATLAB GUI which will only allow numbers or only allow letters to be typed into it.  Is this possible?

Comment: You could try to modify [this script](http://www.biometeorology.umn.edu/matlab/logindlg.m) which replaces characters by stars in an edit box in order to implement a password field.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please take a look, you might find it helpful now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such feature, at least not a documented one.
You could assign a callback that will check the input, but that will happen *after* the user entered illegal character. Though I don't know how exactly to do it, my guess is that you can use Java GUI.
Another interesting option is to add an ActiveX that will do the job.

**Edit:**
I have found an [ActiveX that does the job](http://www.vbforums.com/attachment.php?s=a449d5574ec18467a7e9c3034659a45d&attachmentid=70243&d=1238778210). Downdload it, register by calling

```
Regsvr32 NumberBox.ocx
```

And thein add an ActiveX in Matlab Guide. The name will be **NumberBox.NbrTextBox**.
You can do it by cliking the ActiveX button in Guide:

[image]

Comment: Look on the [undocumented MATLAB](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/) site. There are a range of posts on using the underlying Java objects.