# How to plot an Excel chart in a Matlab's figure

Tags: matlab, activex, ms-office

I want to plot an Excel chart in a figure window of Matlab (i.e. I don't want to execute an out-of-process Excel server by the *actxserver* function). Which control should I use? In fact, the question is more general. How can I use Microsoft Form  controls  here? They aren't represented by default in the list, generated by *actxcontrollist*. I mean such controls that are represented, for example, in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an Excel ActiveX inside Matlab GUI. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853274/can-you-limit-what-characters-can-be-typed-into-a-matlab-gui-editbox/8854217#8854217) explanation that shows how to achieve it using GUIDE.

Comment: but there is no Excel ActiveX in GUIDE's list. I think I have to register it